# CKEditor remove spaces/tabs from between headings

Tags: tabs, newline, ckeditor, spaces

CKEditor does this whenever I add a heading tag:

```
<h2>
    Mai 2010</h2>
```

How can I remove the new line and spaces after the h2 starting tag, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default CKEDITOR behavior for a lot of tag.
To avoid it, open the ckeditor.js file and search for this:
*n.setRules('title',{indent:false,breakAfterOpen:false});*
and add this rule:
*n.setRules('h2',{indent:false,breakAfterOpen:false});*
You can add this rule for each tag you want

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this from the PHP config `side` rather than editing the CORE files?

Comment: I'd also like to know how to do this via PHP config

Comment: Changing the source of plugins/libraries is not appropriate. Because when someone else upgrades a library in your application, someone else will have to figure out why an existing functionality broke.

Answer (score 20):

The way to do this without modifying CKEditor's source is to do the following:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
   {
      ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p',
         {
            indent : false,
            breakBeforeOpen : true,
            breakAfterOpen : false,
            breakBeforeClose : false,
            breakAfterClose : true
         });
   });
```

For more information see:

http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14493 
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting

Comment: +1 I think the question was about the `h2` tag, not the `p` tag but the answer’s great anyway.